# Write a C or a C++ program that reads 10 characters from the user, and then searches for the position of the character z

Tags: c

Write a C or C++ program that reads 10 characters from the user, and then searches for the position of the character 'z'.

How would it be done?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define X 100

int main()
{
    char s1[X];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Char %d = ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", s1);
    }
    
    printf("Char Z index =");
    int index;
    char y = 'z';
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(s1[i] == y)
            index=i;
        // return;
    }
    printf("%d",index);
}
```

Its supposed to tell me the position of the character z

Comment: please do not spam tags. C++ and C are two different languages. If the question is about C then the C++ tag is not relevant

Comment: Why are you using `scanf`?  If you want to read 10 chars, use a reasonable input method.  For this case, `getchar` in a loop is probably easiest, but `fread` would not be a bad idea.

Comment: BTW your program is pure C. Are we talking C or C++?

Comment: @Jabberwocky well actually id want to know either one of them , i wrote mine with C but am looking for both

Comment: Frankly, if you want solutions in both C and C++ you should ask two different questions.  The idiomatic solution in C++ will be *very* different than the C solution.

Comment: @WilliamPursell excuse my miss-use for the website its my first post here

Comment: @WilliamPursell meanwhile do you know the solution avoiding the Code i wrote...

Comment: Are you trying to ignore whitespace?  (your current code seems to be doing that). As I wrote above, just use `getchar` in a loop.  If you don't want to avoid whitespace, do a single `fread`.

Comment: As you intend to store ten values in the array, they need to be stored at `s[0],s[1].....s[9]`...but the current code does not accommodate for this. Hint: Try `scanf("%s", s1 + i);` 

Please take note of the other comments too!!!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following C program prompts the user to enter up to `N` = 10 characters. It reads these characters and stores them in a `char` array with length `N + 1` = 11 (the extra character so that the string is null-terminated, which is the kind of string standard library functions typically assume).

It also makes use of an `N`-element `indices` boolean array to record if position 0, 1, ..., `N` of the message has a `z` or not.

As the program reads a character one at a time, it can modify `indices` should it read a `z`.

Finally, it outputs the message entered as well as the positions of the character `z`.

**I hope this helps. Please let me know if there are any questions or if you wanted something else.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h> /* C99 or above */

#define N 10

int main(void) {

    int ch, i = 0;
    char message[N + 1];
    bool indices[N] = {false};

    printf("Please enter up to 10 characters: ");
    /* read a line of input (max 10 characters) */
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        if (i < N) {
            if (ch == 'z')
                indices[i] = true;

            message[i++] = ch;
        }
    /* null terminate the string */ 
    message[i] = '\0';
    printf("The message entered: %s\n", message);

    printf("Positions of character 'z': ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (indices[i])
            printf("%d, ", i);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Please enter up to 10 characters: zgreeziozz
The message entered: zgreeziozz
Positions of character 'z': 0, 5, 8, 9,
```

Comment: All the Appreciation

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if your problem requires you to take the 10 characters one at a time or all together. If you have to get them all together you could use more simply: `gets(s1);`.
And your compiler may give you an error, as you have defined `int i` inside the  `for` which you can are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode.
Also to check if the z is present inside the string I suggest you do this: `if (s1 == 'z')`.

Furthermore, you cannot input the single characters in that way because every time you enter the next character, the previous one will be automatically deleted and you will reposition the new character in the first position.

Next I advise you to add a `flag==0`in the `for` condition, so that once the `if` condition is `true` we assign `flag=1;` and exit the loop without continuing to search for something we have already found.

In summary:

```html
flag=0;
    for(i = 0; i<10&&flag==0; i++){
        if(s1[i]=='z')
            index=i;
            flag=1;
        // return;
    }
    printf("%d\n",index);
```